# I would like to give a Bounding Box value to a file (preferably guess automatically)

Tags: latex, xelatex

## Description of the problem

I have used PyPlot to save some plots. And, I'm trying to use them in LaTeX. But, then I get an error: `ERROR: LaTeX Error: File` path-to-file/file.bb' not found.`

In normal files, I don't have to specify their Bounding Boxes to them to work. But, if I do specify for this one, it will appear (although floating) in my resulting pdf.

I would like convert, either with ffmpeg, magick, etc. the file so I assure there is an bounding box "shipped" into the image.

### **Current state of affairs:**

##### MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \centering
  \caption{\label{fig:burguer-square} Decay equation with different numerical methods}\\ 
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth, bb=0 0 900 900]{Burguer900.png} # specify Bounding Box
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here is the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FMxVVxgcsrK_Edtoidh_MzPV7KQLchXg/view?usp=sharing

##### Result:

As you can see, the image is floating, furthermore, I have to specify where it is.
[image]

#### MWE2 (without `bb` and logfile)

As required by `@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz`,

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{Resources/Img}{Resources/img}{../../Resources/img}{../../Resources/Img}{~/PP/wlq/Resources/img}{~/PP/wlq/Resources/Img}
  {../../Resources/img/General}
  {../../Resources/img/General2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \centering
  \caption{\label{fig:burguer-square} Decay equation with different numerical methods}   \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Burguer900.png}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

##### RESULT:

error log:
https://pastebin.com/TsN0nkRy

Comment: Why did you tag ImageMagick? I do not see the connection.

Comment: You must not have \\ after your caption (in fact, you never should use \\ anywhere in your document but in tables and similar constructs)

Comment: The `#` after your image is an syntax error -- use % as comment character

Comment: Other than these two errors above, your document works fine for me. However I'm wondering, why do you specify a bounding box? The coordinates you choose add a ton of unnecessary white space around your image and misplace it because they are asymmetric.

Comment: Does it work without the bounding box specification? My problem is exactly what you described, the white space. Without `bb` the image is not working. @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Comment: @fmw42 Because, I want to treat these images, so they have a Bounding Box specification. I don't know if ImageMagick can do this or not - I didn't find anything, but this could be the case.

Comment: @BuddhiLW Without the bb instructions your mwe works perfectly fine and produces a nice and centred image https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA1R9.png

Comment: @BuddhiLW Can you run this code and show your .log file? `\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \centering
  \caption{\label{fig:burguer-square} Decay equation with different numerical methods}
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Burguer900.png} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz https://pastebin.com/TsN0nkRy

Comment: Ah, compiling with xelatex causes the problem

Comment: Can you switch to pdflatex or lualatex?

Comment: Unfortunately not, because the work I'm doing needs xelatex (minted, chinese fonts, unicode etc). But, at least, we know we must use something that changes the images (image processing) itself.

Comment: Are you sure lualatex can't deal with this? It supports unicode, minted ...

Comment: ********************************************
 * XeTeX is required to compile this document.
 * Sorry!
 ********************************************

https://pastebin.pl/view/e463f187